# Representing the birth dates

Tags: .net, database, date, c#-3.0, record

I'm working on a journaling system in C# at our local church, but I've run into trouble with the database connection when storing birth dates. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DATETIME%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) the earlist date possible to represent is January 1st year 1. How am I supposed to record the birth date of Jesus Christ and earlier personalities that are important us?

Comment: I had the same problem when cataloguing dinosaurs fossils(

Comment: MySQL's `datetime` type gets around that problem, although I don't think it can store fossil dates either ;-). Maybe there is something similar in MSSQL (or whatever you're using)?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to roll your own class to handle BC dates in .NET, and store them in the database either as strings or as separate fields for year, month day (depending on what accuracy is required) if you require searching and sorting to be performed on the database side (which I assume you would).

SQL Server's support for dates is more restrictive than .NET's (it only goes back as far as 1753 or 1752 or thereabouts).

[This blog post](http://blog.flipbit.co.uk/2009/03/representing-large-ad-and-bc-dates-in-c.html) is one possible implementation, albeit a pretty limited one as it only stores the year. But I am sure you could modify it as necessary for your needs. For instance, it could probably do well to implement some interfaces such as IComparable, IEquatable, IFormattable and possibly IConvertible as well if you're keen so it can better interact with the rest of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you are free to decide on type of calendar then I would recommend you to go-ahead with the Gregorian calendar, which has the

> ability to recognize two eras: B.C.
>   and A.D.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar.aspx

Comment: First paragraph under Remarks states: "This implementation of the GregorianCalendar class recognizes only the current era (A.D. or C.E.)."

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar.getera(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - store the day, month and year as separate numeric fields. The day and month can be combined into a day-of-the-year value, but you need to watch out for leap years.

Alternative answer - there are standard ways to convert a date into a day-number and back...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

If you do the conversion yourself, you're basically storing a number (that just happens to represent a date) so you should have no problems. Well - other than making sure your conversions are correct.

Comment: From my reading of that Wikipedia entry, the earliest possible date is 4714 BC, and Christian history goes back a little further than that (~12,000 BC - 6,000 BC depending on how you interpret Genesis).

Comment: I thought it was 4004 BC, but then I did get that from Good Omens (http://www.reddit.com/r/firstpage/comments/cu6bh/good_omens_terry_pratchett_neil_gaiman/). Hope that's taken in good humour. Anyway, in principle, you could extend the day numbers backwards - as long as you don't mind some naughtiness. Counting differences between dates and which dates were valid is error-prone anyway, but you could still derive functions that convert a date to/from a number. Not necessarily worthwhile, of course - that depends how you'll use the dates.

Comment: That's error-prone dealing with dates that far back, of course. If you have error ranges spanning from 12,000BC to 6,000BC, a few days out for calendar-definition issues isn't a big deal.

Comment: I don't think that drilling down to the exact day is of any value to the OP's requirements, so that should not be a problem. My memory of the Old Testament is pretty rusty, but I think it rarely concerns itself with anything more precise than the year and possibly the season, and even the latter has to be inferred from context.